# This is googles standard code for getting current location of user on map but on some PC it shows incorrect results. what could be the reason?

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps, geolocation

The code given below is the google's standard code for getting the current geolocation. This code works fine on my android mobile device but it shows my current location to Pune (841 kilometres from my current location), when I accessed the web page from my PC. On one of my friends pc it shows correct location while incorrect location on another friend's PC. Can any one tell why this code shows correct current location on some PC while incorrect on some other?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <head>
            <title>Geolocation</title>
            <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <style>
          html, body, #map-canvas {
            height: 100%;
            margin: 0px;
            padding: 0px
          }
        </style>
        <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&signed_in=true"></script>

        <script>
    // Note: This example requires that you consent to location sharing when
    // prompted by your browser. If you see a blank space instead of the map, this
    // is probably because you have denied permission for location sharing.

    var map;

    function initialize() {
      var mapOptions = {
        zoom: 6
      };
      map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'),
          mapOptions);

      // Try HTML5 geolocation
      if(navigator.geolocation) {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
          var pos = new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude,
                                           position.coords.longitude);

          var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
            map: map,
            position: pos,
            content: 'Location found using HTML5.'
          });

          map.setCenter(pos);
        }, function() {
          handleNoGeolocation(true);
        });
      } else {
        // Browser doesn't support Geolocation
        handleNoGeolocation(false);
      }
    }

    function handleNoGeolocation(errorFlag) {
      if (errorFlag) {
        var content = 'Error: The Geolocation service failed.';
      } else {
        var content = 'Error: Your browser doesn\'t support geolocation.';
      }

      var options = {
        map: map,
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(60, 105),
        content: content
      };

      var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow(options);
      map.setCenter(options.position);
    }

    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

        </script>
      </head>
      <body>
        <div id="map-canvas"></div>
      </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Please help me if any one had solution I have tried a lot but could not find what is the reason for this code showing different current location from different devices.

Comment: Check this. Seems like it is not your end's issue.
http://toddmotto.com/using-html5-geolocation-to-show-current-location-with-google-maps-api/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google's (or anyone's) geolocation stuff isn't *always* accurate. I remember when I moved about 5km down the road to a new house, it still insisted my desktop was back at the old house because (I think) it had detected my router at that location sometime in the past.

I had to get onto Google and basically tell them to delete that knowledge at which point it ended up re-evaluating.

I would say that whatever method being used to locate you (such as network routes to get to you, local WiFi network names, cell tower strengths and so on) is not working too well.

It can be plenty accurate when the device has, for example, a GPS it can query but the methods for desktops aren't necessarily that good.

Comment: Thank for the answer paxdiablo. It is exactly what is happening

Answer (score 0):

Refer this document. It might help.
Using HTML5 Geolocation to show current location with Google Maps API

[http://toddmotto.com/using-html5-geolocation-to-show-current-location-with-google-maps-api/]